# Block elements vs inline elements in HTML: why the distinction?

Tags: html, css

The distinction between block and inline elements always seemed strange to me. The whole difference is that a block element takes up the entire width thus forcing a line break before and after the element, and an inline element only takes up as much as the content. Why not just have one type of element- an inline element where you can also apply custom height/width, and use that? You want line breaks? Insert a `<br />`, or maybe add a special tag in the CSS for that behavior. The way it's now, I don't see it solving any problem, and instead it only forces a property that in my opinion should be decided by a designer.

So why the two types?

Comment: My favorite part of this question is how it uses an inline style for the `<br/>`, and a `<p>` tag to get the last line separated from the first paragraph. Perhaps you should start looking at vast differences in visual intention rather than the differences in implementation.

Comment: While I 100% believe block elements to be useful and disagree with your proposed solution, this is still a great question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You say:

> You want line breaks? Insert a `<br />`, or maybe add a special tag in the CSS for that behavior. The way it's now, I don't see it solving any problem, and instead it only forces a property that in my opinion should be decided by a designer.

You are on the right track - **style should be decided by the designer.**

But, you've got the **problem the other way around.**  Inserting a `<br/>` tag is actually the option that "forces a property that should be decided by a designer" — inside the markup document, once the `<br/>` is there, it's there - and only with some tricky/hacky CSS can you remove its effect.

Inline/block `elements`, on the other hand, are purely elements styled with a convenient default for the common use case.  The visual property itself can be changed instantly by a CSS designer with `display:inline` or `display:block`.

Take for example the common element for navigation these days - `<li>`.  These are by default `block` elements, but designers will make them `float` to appear inline (`block` has more special properties than just taking up the whole line, but that's a conversation for another day).

Answer (score 3):

Most elements have a standard formatting... Your question could be extended to say this formatting should be the decision of the designer as well and should be removed.  I always just figured it was a starting point and removed the formatting if needed (often it wasn't).  But in the end there's some things that are natural.  If you have a paragraph for example you expect it to be a block element because thats the nature of a paragraph.  Regardless of whether or not elements have default settings such as block or inline I definitely would either way want the ability to specify this option. The reason I say this is IMO its cleaner to break things this way versus throwing a `<br />` in the HTML.  Does it do the same thing?  Yes.  But with recent advances in HTML a large effort was focused on making it more of a semantic language where you put less in the HTML as far as formatting goes and more in the CSS. The `<br />` means line break which is typically referring to a line break in a paragraph or other sentence containing structure.  In the end it doesn't matter to me but I personally want the ability to have block and inline distinction so I hope they never remove that from the CSS side at least!

Answer (score 2):

In [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), there are two modes (not including math mode): the horizontal mode and the vertical mode. The elements (characters) are small boxes that accumulate "horizontally" in paragraph. Then these larger boxes accumulate vertically. This is similar to (X)HTML: inline and block.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of like saying there is no real difference between paragraphs and sentences. Paragraphs delimit a *group* of ideas. Typically, a sentence is for a single idea.

The markup is about semantics, not display. Indeed, a designer is free to treat any element that defaults to a block style as inline and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue of backward compatibility to me. The inline element was probably a later addition to the HTML standard, and so that web pages written in 1992 can still be viewed in 2011, it is still supported - like there are a ton of 19 year old web pages out there...!

Answer (score -1):

I think the modes of display are so different between block and inline, that a distinction worth making at the markup level.